# How about including JSON doc version? Is it possible for elastic search, to include different versions of JSON docs, to save and to search?

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using ElasticSearch to save and manage information on complex transactions. We might need to add more information for every transaction, on the near future.
How about including JSON doc version?
Is it possible for elastic search, to include different versions of JSON docs, to save and to search?
How does this affects performance on ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 0):

It's completely possible, By default elastic uses the dynamic mappings for every new documents such as your JSON documents to index them. For each field in your documents elastic creates a table called [inverted_index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/documents-indices.html#:%7E:text=Elasticsearch%20is%20a%20distributed%20document%20store.&text=Elasticsearch%20uses%20a%20data%20structure,documents%20each%20word%20occurs%20in.) and the search queries executed against them so regardless of your field variation as long as you know which field you want to execute query the data throughput and performance will not be affected.